# Implementing a Turn Radius for a Character

Tags: unity, physics, 3d, character-controller

I'm working on a 3rd person platformer in Unity where I'm attempting to capture a Mario 64 style feel. Part of the game involves attaining really fast speeds. Currently, my turning code is pretty simple, and is essentially a mapping of the left-stick onto the character.

Omitting some more complex logic (accounting for smooth acceleration & the like), the base of my movement code is:

```
rigidbody.AddForce(direction * speed);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, normal), delta);
```

This is really responsive and feels good, but at the high speeds the player will attain, it starts to break down. As such, I wanted to add a "turn radius" so that it feels more realistic to attempt to turn at high speeds and face some resistance.

Really, I don't want to go full on "Arthur Morgan" super belabored semicircle turns, but just provide some sense of "weight" and momentum influence to directional changes. Given how simple my current movement is, I'm not sure where to start when it comes to adding in this type of behavior.

I checked out questions like [this mario one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168426/unity3d-replicating-sm64-turning-movement-into-unity) and lots of other turning related questions, but most I could find were related to the direciton the character was facing, and less about it's movement or velocity. Any input here is appreciated!

[image: example of character turning strategies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Methods [`Vector3.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html) or [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) can help you here.

They turn the object towards the desired direction, but put a limit on how far the object is allowed to turn by specifying a `maxDegreeDelta` parameter. So when you put this in your `Update` method to turn the object into the direction of the stick, but set a small `maxDegreeDelta` limit (remember to multiply by `Time.deltaTime`), you have a lazy turning of the character not unlike Mario 64.

If you want to simulate angular momentum and have the rotation be faster at slower speeds and slower and faster speeds, then you might want to adjust the maxDegreeDelta by `rigidbody.velocity.magnitude`.

Comment: Thanks Philipp! This is exactly what I was looking for. After some quick experimentation my character now turns around in a way very remniscent of mario's "semicircle" turn. For future readers: I'm using `rigidbody.velocity.normalized` and my `inputDirection` as the "current" and "target" parameters to `Vector3.rotateTowards`, and I'm then using that resulting calculation in `rigidbody.AddForce`